# unable to visualise graph created by d3.js for a networkx graph in jupyter notebook. "graph.json" file is being created but no visuals appear

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, jupyter-notebook

I am new to javascript and I have written following code to display a networkx graph using d3.js. I am running the code in jupyter notebook. I am not getting any output. No errors, no visualisation.

```
import json
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
data = json_graph.node_link_data(G[0])
with open('graph.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)


` %%html
    <div id="d3-example"></div>
    <style>
    .node {stroke: #fff; stroke-width: 1.5px;}
    .link {stroke: #999; stroke-opacity: .6;}
    </style>`



 %%javascript
    require(["d3"], function(d3){
    var force = d3.layout.force().charge(-120).linkDistance(30).size([width, height]);
    var svg = d3.select("#d3-example").select("svg");
    d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
    force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start();
    var link = svg.selectAll(".link").data(graph.links).enter().append("line").attr("class", "link");
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(graph.nodes).enter().append("circle")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.club);
    })
    .call(force.drag);
    });
});`
```

Comment: Looks like you have an empty selection here: `var svg = d3.select("#d3-example").select("svg");` - you have an element with the ide `d3-select`, but it doesn't contain an svg. You could try to add an svg to the `d3-example` div: `<div id="d3-example"><svg width="960" height="500"></svg></div>`, but I'm also not seeing things needed for a force layout such as a tick function.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but the problem is that I am absolutely new to this environment. I haven't used a javascript library such as d3.js for visualisation. I work in python and I basically want to visualise a networkx graph. Can you guide me towards a more apt methodology.

Comment: I added a tick function, Can you please verify the error.

Comment: Without seeing your tick function or if you updated the code in terms of an svg - I'm afraid I can't do any more to help. If you edit in the tick function and any other changes it will help.